# Web API - Return JSON object along with the HTTP Status

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler

I have this Web API function that I wish to use to return errors if any invalid data is passed in. I do this by using the Request.CreateResponse function, and passing it the error code and list of errors.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Lead leadToCreate)
    {
           // Code to validate the request, and populate errorList which is a List<Error> goes here        

            if (errorList.Count > 0)
            {
                // Return list of errors and 304 code
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotModified, errorList);
            }
            else
            {
                //Validated successfully.
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            }

   }
```

The Error class is:

```
public class Error
{
    public int number;
    public string description;
    public string url;
}
```

When I make a POST request with Fiddler on localhost, the error list is output as part of the JSON response (see the last line):

> HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Expires: -1
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>
> X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcU291cmNlIENvZGVcV2ViXEZhc3R0cmFjayBBUElcRmFzdHRyYWNrIEFQSVxhcGlcc2FsZXNFbnF1aXJ5XDFc?=
>
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2016 14:49:20 GMT
>
> **[{"number":1,"description":"PrivateIndividual.Gender must be valid.","url":""}]**

My problem is that after publishing to my live server, the error list isn't output despite using the same request data, although the correct response code is returned:

> HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
>
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 10 Feb
>
> 2016 14:52:13 GMT Connection: close X-ScanSafe-Error: F284 Via:
>
> HTTP/1.1 proxy10012

Can anyone see why this may be working fine on localhost, but not my live server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an application layer proxy having a problem with the response:

```
2016 14:52:13 GMT Connection: close X-ScanSafe-Error: F284 Via:

HTTP/1.1 proxy10012
```

And it looks like this proxy is blocking the HttpResponse from getting back to fiddler.

Comment: Thank you! I logged off my office's network, used my phone as a hot spot and tried the request again and it worked perfectly.